# Input Special Characters through $_GET.

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$Tags=$_REQUEST['Tags'];
$CategoryId=$_REQUEST['CategoryId'];
var_dump($Tags);
```

and my input is:

**baseurl/project/controller/method?CategoryId=3&Tags=Other,testcase,Bar & restaurant,Dining**

when i give input like that,i get error ***'disallowed key values'***.... I know that the error is because of Special character '&' in Bar & restaurant.....
How do i pass Bar & restaurant  without getting error

Comment: http://php.net/urlencode

Comment: Try adding $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-zA-Z 0-9~%.:_()@\-\&,'; in your config

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to pass parameters through url with characters like `,`. You can encode the string you want to pass (Other,testcase,Bar ).

Try like :

```
$vars = urlencode(join(',', array(Other,testcase,Bar)));
```

Pass though url like

```
aseurl/project/controller/method?CategoryId=3&Tags=<?php echo $vars ?>
```

Process it in the resultant page

```
$vars = explode(',', urldecode($_GET['Tags']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Certain characters cannot be used directly. Use `urlencode()` http://php.net/urlencode This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL.

Answer (score -1):

You should encode it, so & would be `&amp;`

This can be done with the `htmlspecialchars()` function, see the documentation [here](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)